# Ever see duplicate IDs when using Google App Engine and ndb?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

[image: Appengine production db]

```
class Entries(ndb.Model):
  description = ndb.StringProperty()
  seqid = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  link = ndb.StringProperty()
  group = ndb.StringProperty()
  timestamp = ndb.StringProperty()
  referrals = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

The two entries in the picture are created by two different users. The user is the parent of the Entry.

I get a duplicate ID on production but not on local. Also, it's always this same id number (but it is certainly not hard coded anywhere)

As the parent is the user, i can still pull it as a unique entry but it will mean there will be problems if I have two entries with the same parent user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A datastore's unique key is the fully qualified key, including all parent entity keys, not just the ID. Multiple entities with the same ID and different parents are completely valid, and you shouldn't rely on the id alone being unique.

Comment: yes i understand that however if it allows duplicate IDs then it means I can't have two entries with the same parent within this table and that just crazy!

Comment: Duplicate IDs can happen for entities with different parents because they have their own ID counters. It's not possible for two entities with auto-generated IDs to get the same generated ID if they have the same parent.

Comment: aha, I have not tested that yet. I'm not overly happy with the oddity of duplicates so I may trying allocating ids and see what happens.

Comment: or maybe I'll just be a good boy and accept things as they are Nick... duplicates happen

Comment: @kullar This is just part of how App Engine allocates IDs - each parent and kind tuple has its own ID counter. Duplicates can happen between (parent, kind) tuples, but not on the same one - there wouldn't be much point in ID allocation otherwise.

Comment: I read your other explanation on how to think about appengine datastore and, along with this, it makes more sense. Cheers Nick.